# DirectoryEntry class not recognized

Tags: vb.net, directoryservices

```
Imports System
Imports System.DirectoryServices
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim oroot As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://domain.com/OU=Departments,DC=domain,DC=com")
        Dim osearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(oroot)
        Dim oresult As SearchResultCollection
        Dim result As SearchResult
        Dim list As New List(Of String)
```

I am trying to build a dropdown box to query the user name from AD from my client. Directory entry class is not getting recognized. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you add a reference to System.DirectoryServices.dll to your project ?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely missing the reference to `System.DirectoryServices`. Adding the line `Imports...` is not sufficient, you also have to add a reference. Right click on References under your project in the Solution Explorer, and click on Add Reference. Select `System.DirectoryServices`. If you ever see this issue for other classes, you can find the assembly (reference) name by looking up the MSDN page for the class. Top two things should always be "Namespace" (which is what you need on the `Imports...` line), and `Assembly` which is what you need a reference to.

Some additional tips:

If you have a lot of user objects, set `PageSize` on the `DirectorySearcher`, otherwise it will only return the first 1,000 user objects (not sure if that's the exact number). Doesn't necessarily matter what you set it as long as it's > 0.

```
osearcher.PageSize = 1000
```

Add some [filters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.filter(v=vs.110).aspx) to get rid of non-user objects.

```
Dim osearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(oroot, _
    "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))")
```

Use `PropertiesToLoad` as it will significantly make your query faster.

```
osearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName")
osearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName")
```